# Samba Fileshare: Is it possible to create a public (guest) share which is protected by a password?

Tags: linux, debian, samba

I have a public Samba share deployed on my network. Currently this is somewhat a security risk.

I am aware that I can create individual user accounts, with associated passwords, as a form of security, however is it possible to protect the share using a single password, effectively a master password?

OS is Debian 10.

Comment: What is the difference with creating a user "Public" with a password, and share that password? Note that password-sharing is also a serious security risc.

Comment: @LjmDullaart It's just for a home network share. I can give the password to someone else in the house if they want to access something, but there is that layer of protection there to prevent someone accidentally mounting the share and deleting everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the 'guest' user with 'guest ok = yes' set on a share is generally the user 'nobody' which doesn't have a password. What you could do is create a user with a password, remove 'map to guest = bad user' from global and 'guest ok = yes' from the share, add 'valid user = your_new_user' to the share and use the username and password when connecting to the share. This isn't much more secure than using guest access, but you could at least change the password regularly.

Answer (score 1):

When a user connects as a guest to a samba share, authenticating with a username and password is unnecessary. So the short answer is 'no'.

It is however perfectly feasible to create a user `visitor` with specific access-rights and give that user a password. That would functionally fulfill your requirement.

The remark about shared passwords (that it is not a secure thing to do) is still valid. You should be aware of the limited assurance that such a set-up provides.

Also note, that this should be quite different from the master password. Typically, a master password provides more authorization than you should be giving to your guests (visitors). For clarity sake, don't call it a master password.